# Adding a single item to javascript namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Supposing I have the following:

```
var nameSpace = {
    first: 'a',
    second: 'b',
    third: 'c'
}
```

How can I add a single item, to make it:

```
var nameSpace = {
    first: 'a',
    second: 'b',
    third: 'c',
    foo: 'foostring'
}
```

?

Would nameSpace.foo = "foostring" work?

thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you have tried it faster than asking this question? :)

Comment: I always realize the answer to my own question while formulating it in writing!

Comment: That's not a namespace. That's an object.

Comment: @recursive. This question can end up with a reversal badge... I'm missing only 19 upvotes... `:)`

Comment: It is important to realize that `nameSpace` is just a *variable* which names an `Object` and that objects have *properties* which are mappings of [stringified] keys (such as `first`, `foo`, etc.) to values (such as 'a' or 'foostring'). There is no concept of "namespaces" in JavaScript (only various scoping and lookup rules which are more universal and not demonstrated here).

Comment: People who upvote questions like this shouldn't be allowed to vote.

Answer (score 3):

> Would nameSpace.foo = "foostring" work?

**Yes**, why didn't you try?